# Base Class library for NTP client in .NET?

Tags: .net, ntp

Is there any .NET BCL for NTPClient?

I have seen a few implementations of NTPClient [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#GawBxmf1je8/NTP/NtpClient.cs&q=ntp%20lang:c%23&l=34) and [here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidC58B67A7B40913517FD7F30082E36230C4B90C46.aspx?s=socket#L4).

But does .net provide any library for doing this?

Comment: there is no out of the box NTP client in .NET

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There appears to be no BCL for .NET; We have to write our own libraries, examples of which are documented in the question.